# Adding brackets after paricular string

Tags: awk, sed

I want to add () after the equal symbol as shown below.

actual variable in a file :  `vm_names=vm1 vm2 vm3`

i want to change it to: `vm_names=(vm1 vm2 vm3)`

I tried the below command but its giving different output

```
sed -i 's/.*/(&)/' file_name
```

O/p: (vm_names=vm1 vm2 vm3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the file `test.txt` has multi lines:

```
name1=v1 v2 v3

name2=v4 v5 v6

...
```

Do this command `while read -r line; do line=${line/=/=(}; line="$line)"; echo $line; done < test.txt`

**Explain**:

- Replace `=` by `=(`
- Add `)` to the end of each line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sed -i 's/=\(.*\)/=(\1)/' file_name
```

*Details*

- `=\(.*\)` - matches `=` and then captures into Group 1 the rest of the string
- `=(\1)` - replaces with `=(` + Group 1 value and a `)`.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/3mSS7U):

```sh
s='vm_names=vm1 vm2 vm3'
sed 's/=\(.*\)/=(\1)/' <<< "$s"
# => vm_names=(vm1 vm2 vm3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. This will print the results on terminal and once you are happy with results you can use `-i` option to do a inplace editing into Input_file itself.

```
sed 's/=/&(/;/=/s/$/)/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply substituting `=` with `=(` and then appending `)` at last of the line too as per requirement.

Comment: Hi bro @RavinderSingh, its working thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

another `sed` which implements your logic

```
sed -i '/=/s/[^=]*$/(&)/' file
```

if line matches `=` sign, wrap everything on the righthand side with parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```sh
$ echo 'vm_names=vm1 vm2 vm3' | awk -F= '{print $1 FS "(" $2 ")"}'
vm_names=(vm1 vm2 vm3)
```

- `-F=` set `=` as input field separator
- `$1` and `$2` has content of first and second field
- `FS` variable stores the input field separator
- `"("` and `")"` are two string literals
- strings placed next to each other get concatenated

With `perl`:

```sh
$ echo 'vm_names=vm1 vm2 vm3' | perl -pe 's/=\K.+/($&)/'
vm_names=(vm1 vm2 vm3)
```

- `=\K` matches `=` character, but not part of matched portion available via `$&` variable
- `.+` rest of the line after `=` character

Answer (score 1):

I would use `AWK` for that following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
vm_names=vm1 vm2 vm3
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="="}{print NF==2?$1"=("$2")":$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
vm_names=(vm1 vm2 vm3)
```

Assumptions: every line in `file.txt` has at most 1 `=`. Explanation: set field separator (FS) to be `=` then print if we have 2 fields what is before `=` followed by `=(` followed by what is after `=` followed by `)` else whole line as is (`$0`)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Also with `awk` you can try:

```
awk '{gsub(/=/,"=(");$NF=$NF")"} 1' file
vm_names=(vm1 vm2 vm3)
```

This code: simply substituting `=` with `=(` and then appending `)` at the end of the last field.